# Getting User details from Push API checkin

Tags: foursquare

I'm using Foursquare Push APIs in our server. It's working just fine but for one problem. I'm accessing user checkins in my php file as:

`$jsonresponse = json_decode($_REQUEST["checkin"]);`

and for the user I'm obtaining firstname, lastname etc as usual. But when I try to access user details (email etc.) by:

`$jsonresponse->user->contact->email`

it returns a blank field. I'm testing with my own 4Sq account so I know my email value is present. Am I missing something?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Push API calls contain a compact user as opposed to a full user object (see: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/user). You'll need to retrieve the full user details to access the contact information (/users/self)